# Spring Oauth2 and Rest Backend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have successfully followed this tutorial. 
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver

However I can't seem to make it work using it as a rest backend service. I always get the login page from the Authorization Server instead.

How can I make it work?

I'm using the following header with a post.

```
Authorization: Bearer <my access token from facebook>
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

The client/resource server looks like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class ClientApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Principal user) {
        return "Hello " + user.getName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ClientApplication.class)
            .properties("spring.config.name=client").run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The authorization server get accessed first before going to the resource server that is why your always seeing the page from authorization server. I would suggest you to have good understanding of OAuth2 concept. I followed this tutorial and it's very helpful. 
[http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/][1]

Comment: So basically I need to disable the login form on the authorization server and make the resource server use rest to authorize the posted access token, right?

Edit: I want to use Facebook as authorization server and I don't want to create custom user/userdetails myself.

Comment: Here I believe your trying to use facebook oauth2 as authorization server right? If that is the case then you need to do what you said about remove the login form from authorization server.